# Sql select sorted group with limit

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, sql-order-by

I have sql issue. 
For example, i have table leads with column id,name, datum_event.

In my table are 2000 records.

I need do this: sort all records by datum_event (has date format), group all records by name, and then sort groups by datum_event.

For example, i have leads:

```
1     Name1   2019-05-06
2     Name1   2019-10-04
3     Name1   2019-08-06
4     Name2   2019-04-06
5     Name2   2019-20-04
6     Name3   2019-01-06
```

And i need on page show only 2 leads.
So for one page result is:

```
5     Name2   2019-20-04
4     Name2   2019-04-06
```

For second page is:

```
2     Name1   2019-10-04
1     Name1   2019-05-06
```

For third page is:

```
3     Name1   2019-08-06
6     Name3   2019-01-06
```

Is it possible do with mysql? Because now i do this with php, and i need get all records from table (2000!), then loop all records and make groups, then sort records and is very very slow.

How can i solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think you are looking for:

```
select t.*
from t
order by min(datum_event) over (partition by name),
         name,
         datum_event desc;
```

This returns names in the order of their earliest event.  Within a name, it then orders by the events in reverse date order.

Edit:

In older versions of MariaDB, you can express this as:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select name, min(datum_event) as min_datum_event
      from t
      group by name
     ) n
     on t.name = n.name
order by n.min_datum_event,
         name,
         datum_event desc;
```

Comment: I run 'select * from leads order by min(leads.datum_event) over (partition by leads.name), leads.name, leads.datum_event desc;' but get error 'check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'over (partition by leads.name), leads.name, leads.datum_event desc '